ALSA underruns and overruns on process fork() call
This is a rather surprising issue. In my application ALSA is handling constant audio streaming between multiple nodes, the whole application is made out of multiple threads, each assigned to a unique function.
One of the threads starts a sub-process in order to run the execl command, the very moment fork() is called ALSA throws errors as below, resulting in audible clicks and pops. Interestingly, even running fork() with a subprocess code returning immediately throws the ALSA errors.
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.2.6.1/src/pcm/pcm.c:8568:(snd_pcm_recover) overrun occurred

The CPU usage isn't higher than usually during the fork() call and the sub-process is not taking much CPU either. The software is run on a raspberrypi CM4. What could be the cause, what is the solution?
